# OData collection bound function, keep getting 404

Tags: c#, function, collections, odata

Im truly stuck.. I just cant figure out how to get this working..
I want to create a custom function and bind it to the following url:

http://localhost:[someport]/odata/Dealers/SomeFunction

Where odata is my route-prefix, Dealers is my DealersController and SomeFunction is my custom function.

I have done the following to "register" the function:

```
builder.EntityType<Dealer().Collection.Function("SomeFunction").Returns<string>();
```

And this is my function:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult SomeFunction()
{
    return Ok("Some");
}
```

But as soon as Im requesting the above mentioned url.. nothing happens..

Could someone please give me some guidance.

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the namespace in the URL

http://localhost:[someport]/odata/Dealers/[namespace].SomeFunction

the namespace is default if not specified or can be set like this:

```
builder.Namespace = "MyNamespace";
```

And if you are using IIS, add these lines to your config file

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
 </system.webServer>
```

If you are using OdataV4 you can also enable the call without the namespace by enabling unqualified name to the HttpConfiguration

```
config.EnableUnqualifiedNameCall(unqualifiedNameCall: true);
```